# clearInterval(); doesn't work given the setInterval's ID

Tags: javascript

First off, I don't want the function to start running as soon as I open the file, **secondly I can't stop the interval...**

I've tried the `setInterval(sing, 1000)` and get a number 7 but I can't stop the code by doing `clearInterval(7)`

```js
function sing() {
    console.log("twinke twinke...");
    console.log("adadasdsad...");
}

setInterval(sing, 1000);
```

Comment: Did you manually get the `7` during the first run and then sometimes later try to clear `7`?  You should not inspect that value, you should just pass it around.

Comment: The ID returned by `setInterval` is different everytime you call it. So, store it in a variable, and pass the variable to `clearInterval`

Answer (score 2):

The ID to stop the interval is the result of "setInterval".
For example:

```
// starting setInterval
const id = setInterval(() => {
 // do something...
}, 1000);

// to stop the interval
clearInterval(id);
```